# Why is powershell running an external program in the same console window if a leading space is added to path?

Tags: powershell

I managed to fluke the solution to a problem.

I was having problems calling an external program from within a powershell script without having a separate window pop up.

This was not working for me:

```
$Plink = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe "
$Login = "password details"
$PName = "ls -lrt"
echo "Start"

$Output = invoke-expression "& `"$Plink`" $Login $PName " 
$Output
```

The code ran fine but the plink console opened in another window.

This however solved my problem:

```
$Plink = " C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe "
$Login = "password details"
$PName = "ls -lrt"
echo "Start"

$Output = invoke-expression "& `"$Plink`" $Login $PName " 
$Output
```

The only difference is the leading space in front of the $Plink path. Thanks to this space, the plink call was executed in the same window and did exactly what I wanted.

My question is why a leading space would have this effect? My concerns are 1) I don't understand how a space makes a difference and 2) Because I fluked it, the code might stop working on another pc or following a update.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make any difference for me, plink behaves the same either way. Is it repeatable - if you take the space away a new window appears? (What window?)

Comment: I get the same result every time. Without a space, an ordinary dos command prompt window opens and runs the plink commands and the closes. Very strange.

Comment: You don't need `Invoke-Expression`. Just run `& "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe" $Login $PName`.

Comment: That kinda works but the variables are being passed to plink as literal strings so the command fails with 'unable to open connection'.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce that. You must be doing something different from what I'm doing.

Comment: The problem is that your command ends with space as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I'm using Bill suggestion of just using & instead of invoke-expression and it works fine.